# How can I use Inertia to make a fetch request to a route behind `auth:api` middleware?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-9, inertiajs

I have a Laravel app with a number of routes behind `auth:api`. I'd like those routes to be available to users in my Dashboard.

I've tried the following on a route that I have named `api.me` that is behind `auth:api`, but Inertia does not provide the Authorization header.

```
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-react";
...
const { data, setData, errors, get } = useForm({});
...
get(route('api.me'));
```

I assume the route must be behind the `auth` middleware instead. If so, is it possible to have it use both the `auth` and `auth:api` middlewares?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best way to handle this is to provide the data via the controller or route.

The route should return:

```php
Route::get('/subscription', function() {
    return Inertia::render('some/route', [
        'me_info' => Auth::user(),
        'other_data' > ['some' => 'other data']
    ]);
});
```

If you are using React, the `me_info` and `other_data` will be made available to the component props.